# How do I update user status on database in spring?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, schedule

I have such as the below source. I use spring,jpa. 
The first time a user status is a smile. But after 30 minutes, I want the database value to automatically change to sad.

I think the below source should continue in the background. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String createUser(@RequestBody UserInformation user) throws Exception{

    userDataService.createUser(user);
    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    json.addProperty("STATUS", "SUCCESS");

    return json.toString();
}
```

service

```
public void createUser(UserInformation user){
    user.setState("smile"); //first database status change
    userInformationDAO.add(user);


    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            user.setState("sad"); //after 30 minute second database status change
        }
    }, 1000 * 60 * 30);
}
```

Comment: You could add a column with a timestamp of when the state was last set. Then when you request the state, you first check the statSetTimestamp. If it was set more than 30 minutes ago you change the state to 'sad' and you can go on with your flow.

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker is it available statSetTimestamp functuon  in mysql?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. statSetTimestamp would just be an extra column. You then fill it from your code with the current timestamp or you can write a database trigger for it to be filled in on every insert.